# set element in arraylist updating other elements also

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have one arraylist with custom object.

```
    Object {
    String price;
    String discountedPrice;
    int discount;
    String id;
   }
```

When ever I add any new object in Arraylist, I'll set price of all elements to discountPrice by traversing arraylist.

Problem Statement:
Whenever new object added in Arraylist apply discount on previous objects.
e.g. Rs.399, Rs. 499, Rs. 399 added in arraylist.
So when 399 added no discount.
when 499 added apply 2% discount on 399.
Then 399 become 399-2% = 392.
then when 399 added apply 2% discount on 499 and 392-2%.
I added one common method in which first set all price to discountedPrice.
then check size of arraylist and traverse upto size -2 means second last element to apply discount.
int diff use to check how many elements are there after this element to apply discount on that object.

But whenever id of element is same then it applies to all ids.

```
private void calculateDiscounted() {
    int size = arraylist1.size();
    if(size > 1){
        int index = size - 2;
        for(int i = 0; i <= index; i++){
                   int diff = index - i ;
                calculateDiscountPrice(diff, arraylist1.get(i), i);

        }
    }
}

private void calculateDiscountPrice(int diff, CustomObject object, int position) {
    CustomObject object = object;
    for( int i = 0; i <= diff; i++){
        int discount = 2;
        int price = Integer.valueOf(object.getDiscoutprice());
        int amtDiscount = (price * discount) / 100;
        int discountPrice = price - amtDiscount;
        object.setDiscount(amtDiscount);
        object.setdiscountedPrice(String.valueOf(discountPrice));
    }
    arraylist1.set(position, object);
}
```

Comment: So why don't you check ID before updating row?

Comment: Why are you checking elements after the index when you want to apply discount to previous objects?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, but you should have required getter and setter methods in your Bean class

```
void addNewObject(Custom object, ArrayList<CustomObject> al){
  for(int i = 0;i<al.size();i++){
    CustomObject c=al.get(i);
    int price=c.getPrice();
    int discount=0.02*price;
    c.setDiscount(discount);
    c.setDiscountedPrice(price-discount);
    al.set(i,c);
  }
  al.add(object);
}
```

Comment: I already have that object just need to calculate price and set to that position. If i create object and then add to arraylist it will add another element.

Comment: May be i have misunderstood your question ..but if u want to update all the previous elements the before add new object update all the elements in the ArrayList (NO need to calculate the index).

Comment: to update u can get the object ...make changes and then use set method which will replace the previious element at that position